# Spring boot can not send out any e-mail with the GSuite account

Tags: spring-boot, google-workspace

I am trying to send an e-mail by Java code. Previously, I set up with a normal Gmail account like below:

```
spring.mail.username=myaccount@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=apppassword
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
```

​​It worked!
But when I changed to use adminis@mydomain.com and set up like below:

```
spring.mail.username=adminis@mydomain.com
spring.mail.password=apppassword
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
```

​​I could not send anymore and received a message:

```
**Username and Password not accepted**
```

Please help! the less secured app is not the problem because I use the app password and it worked on the Gmail account without turned on the LSA.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [guide](https://www.exclamationsoft.com/exclamationsoft/netmailbot/help/reference/find_mail_server.asp#:%7E:text=Type%20%22nslookup%22.,com%22%20or%20your%20domain%20name.)! to find the mail host.
Then use that mail host instead of smtp.gmail.com.

Or use mail.yourdomain.com or smtp.yourdomain.com as mail host